# Regex to match a pattern within quotes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match and substitute a pattern.

Test String: `{1-Emp Name: "John", "2-Emp pat" : 1123,"3-Emp lwd" : 20}, "4-Emp Pat" : 1234}`

I'm trying to match the pattern with the word "pat" from the test string and substitute

Expected Result: `{1-Emp Name: "John", "matched Pattern" : 1123,"3-Emp lwd" : 20}, "matched Pattern" : 1234}`

My regex: `".+?(?i)Pat.+?(?=:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

*Regex pattern*: `(?i)"[^"]* Pat\b[^"]*("\s*:)`
*Replacement pattern*: `"matched pattern$1`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iq6Jkx/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `Pat` - space + `Pat` word
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[^"]*`  - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `("\s*:)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `"`, zero or more whitespaces, `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler regex is:

```
:%s/\<[^,]\+\(p\|P\)at\>/matched Pattern/g
```